# How i can make Pycharm cycle through completion suggestions via 'Tab' key?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

For example, i want to complete following statement:

```
foo = []
foo.a|
     +-----------+
     | append    |
     | __add__   |
     | clear     |
     | class     |
     | contains  |
     +-----------+
```

i hit 'Tab':

```
foo = []
foo.append|
     +-----------+
     | append    |
     | __add__   |
     | clear     |
     | class     |
     | contains  |
     +-----------+
```

hit once more

```
foo = []
foo.__add__|
     +-----------+
     | append    |
     | __add__   |
     | clear     |
     | class     |
     | contains  |
     +-----------+
```

...and so on.
I saw this feature in Linux shells and Sublime text, but i can't find any settngs in Pycharm to implement such behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I could get to your request is cycle the choice list with one pair of keys then choose the selection with tab. I realize that this is not a perfect solution but it works well for me.

The up and down keyboard keys will cycle through completions, if you want different keys to perform the 'Up' and 'Down' action, then goto

Settings --> Keymap --> Editor Actions

then add additional mappings for Up and Down. I come from Vim so I added ctrl-k and ctrl-j for Up and Down respectively. You will get a warning about another mapping already existing but was some thing that I would rarely use so I was ok with it.

Coming from years of using Vim, my first choice was to use ctrl-n and ctrl-p but that did not work for me for reasons I was not able to figure out. My second choice is somewhat intuitive for my Vim trained brain where k and j are up and down in command mode.

Answer (score -1):

Is `Alt+/` what you need? In `PyCharm` also has some other autocomplete shortcuts, for example `Ctrl+Space` shortcut.

You could adjust keys in `PyCharm` settings:

`Settings --> Keymap --> search by "Completion" word`

Comment: Please, try to perform your answer on my example data and answer "Do you got same results as me?" BTW, do you think that I'm so dumb and can't even check completion settings? I do ask because there is no obvious way to do what i need.